# Magento 2 Migration tool

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

We are using Magento CE 2.1.2, trying out the Magento 2 migration from a CE 1.9.0.2.

Migration works as expected with no problems except for "delta", that doesn't update any order or customer after the initial migration, also if the newer db given has more orders and customers than the one used for the initial migration.

We didn't found errors or anything on logs, and so far shell output says everything is ok.

Here is the log from shell:

```
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Map Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Log Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Log Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Migration completed successfully
    [2016-12-02 09:44:40][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Automatic restart in 5 sec. Use CTRL-C to abort
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Map Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Log Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Log Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Migration completed successfully
    [2016-12-02 09:44:45][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Automatic restart in 5 sec. Use CTRL-C to abort
```

Comment: Please execute this after delta migration : `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into the source database, you should have some extra tables with `m2_cl_` prefix.

[image: Magento2 Data Migration Tool]

Those tables are the ones used to log all changes since the initial migration.